# config.properties NullPointerException

Tags: java, properties, config

I have a config.properties file in which are stored the credentials for a database, but when I try to read it I get a NullPointerException, Any Ideas??

Folder Structure:

com/mypackage/config

- DbConnector.java
- config.properties

DbConnection Class

```
final String PROPERTIES_FILE = "com\\mypackage\\Config\\config.properties";
        InputStream inputStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream(PROPERTIES_FILE);
        Properties dbProperties = new Properties();

        dbProperties.load(inputStream); //The run doesn't pass this point
```

The Exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.util.Properties$LineReader.readLine(Properties.java:434)
at java.util.Properties.load0(Properties.java:353)
at java.util.Properties.load(Properties.java:341)
at     com.cetys.cetyslibraryinventory.Config.DataBaseConnector.retrieveConnectionParameters(DataBaseConnector.java:68)
```

I know this must be that the file is not found but why? Any Ideas?

Update

If I change the path to "src\main\java\com\mypackage\config\config.properties" it works, but I don't like that kind of hard coded approach is there any more programmaticaly way?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a absolute path to the `config.properties` filename ? 
Also is the `config.properties` file in the same folder as `DbConnection` class? If that is the case then just write 
`final String PROPERTIES_FILE = "config.properties";`

Comment: You just updated that the absolute path works! That means the relative path is wrong . Try preceding the relative path using "\" and check.

Answer (score 0):

My projet was using maven, so I move the file to the main/resources folder and
change the path as

```
String PROPERTIES_FILE = "config.properties";
    InputStream inputStream = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()
               .getResourceAsStream(PROPERTIES_FILE);
    Properties dbProperties = new Properties();

    dbProperties.load(inputStream);
```

And everything works.

Thanks